# How many stroke does Chinese Traditional Word "蕭" have?

Tags: radicals, strokes

I have referred to

[China Mainland Online Dictionary](http://www.zdic.net/z/23/js/856D.htm)

and
[Online Stroke Order Dictionary of Ministry of Education of Republic of China](http://stroke-order.learningweb.moe.edu.tw/characterQueryResult.do?word=%E8%95%AD)

Both are giving different numbers of stroke for this word.
China Mainland: 18 Total Strokes.
Republic of China: 16 Total Strokes.

But I counted myself, it is 17 strokes. 
丨一 一丨乛 一 一丨丿丨丨乛丨一 乛 一丨

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look of this pictures:

10th stroke is:

[image]

11th stroke is:

[image]

12th stroke is:

[image]

14th stroke is:

[image]

15th stroke is:

[image]

16th stroke is:

[image]

voila, 16 strokes :)

Comment: But you see, the 10th stroke, it is only one stroke to finish.
How do we call this type stroke? 豎折? Normally 豎折 is 豎 then 折 to right side. 

I have found the similar word, which is 片, the stroke is 先豎後橫, not even 豎折，does not like the 10th stroke above.

Comment: well, i don't know the chinese name :( it unicode code point u+31d8 http://www.charbase.com/31d8-unicode-cjk-stroke-swz it's english name is cjk stroke swz. give me some time, i'll try to search :)

Comment: Please refer to this webpage,
[link](http://chukaml.tripod.com/linguistics/unicode/codeChart/U0031C0.html)
Ctrl+F -- 31D8：㇘

It is known as 豎彎左。

I'm Malaysian-born Chinese, I'm educated in Simplified Chinese, that's why I don't know a lot of 部件、筆順、注音 in Traditional Chinese Characters. I can read long time ago, but only start writing few years ago.

Comment: thanks, great info. last, i'm curious, may i ask why you need to learn chinese?

Comment: I'm Chinese, I have to learn Chinese, I start learning Chinese when I was 4; start speaking Chinese when I was a toddler. May be you are thinking the Malaysia official language is Malay, but as it is stated in the Constitution, 各族人民可以自行學母語。And the reason why I learn TRADITIONAL CHINESE because I think that I have already been brainwashed by the Communist Chinese Government so many years. Have to follow Mr. Sun Yat Sen‘s’ Three People's Principles. HAHA
You're from Taiwan (Republic of China)? Glad to meet you here.

Comment: i see :) i always find that reasons of learning one language are the most interesting. for your situation, you've foundation, learning traditional chinese is not difficult; carry on 　

Comment: Haha thank you so much, you too, all the best in future.

Comment: I'd like to know exactly how the 10th stroke is written. Is it going from top to bottom then RIGHT TO LEFT? The later part is unusual in Chinese writing. Or is it from left to right (the lower part) then GOING UP? That's also unusual. To abide to the rule of Chinese writing, it seems to me the 10th stroke has to be broken into two strokes. That would make it 17 strokes, not 16.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... I see 18 strokes in this particular version of "Xiao/Siu".